# Is it possible to know the maximum MTU size supported based on Android version?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-ble, mtu

I know the way to increase the MTU size of packets exchanged between android device and a bluetooth peripheral is done using `BluetoothGatt.requestMtu(int mtu)` and `BluetoothGattCallback.onMtuChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, int mtu, int status)`

But is it possible to know this information based on the Android version ?

For example, is there some rules such as "Devices on Android 9 or less will not support an MTU size of more than n bytes" ?